# Textbox updates itself while typing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following textbox binded to a MVVM ViewModel

Textbox

```
<TextBox Height="71" Width="341" 
         Text="{Binding BalanceValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N2}"
         Margin="0,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

Below is my `ImportPresenter` Which handles the input.

```
Public Class ImportPresenter : ObservableObject
{
    private double _BalanceValue = 0;

    public double BalanceValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _BalanceValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _BalanceValue = double.Parse(value.ToString(), 
                            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("BalanceValue");
        }
    }//END BALANCEVALUE
}
```

For the most part, this works, except when testing, The `TextBox` is updating itself while I'm typing. Should I use a different event for the `TextBox`?

Comment: How would you like it to behave? Currently, you're telling the ViewModel to update every time the text box's property is changed, and it's immediately parsing the value, updating, and notifying the View that the property has changed. Are you wanting it to update when you remove focus instead, or maybe have a delay before updating?

Comment: I'd like the `_BalanceValue` to update after the user is finished inputting the text

Comment: Why are you using `double.Parse` on a value that's already a `double`?

Comment: I thought I had to. I don't have to? I was assuming the value coming in from the textbox could be a text. If it doesn't, I'll take it out :)

Comment: In this case - I'd consider Jack's answer below to be correct.

Comment: In a property setter, `value` will be of the same type as the property. If you hover over it, you should see the type.

Comment: Aaaaaaaand I'm dumb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `UpdateSourceTrigger` for the `TextBox` is `Lost Focus`. By setting it to `PropertyChanged` it will update for every change made, e.g. every character.

Answer (score 5):

in some situations updating viewmodel on `LostFocus` and on every `PropertyChanged` is equally inconvenient. (e.g. typing key word for search - we don't want to run search after each letter, we want to do it when users stop typing - but they don't leave search field)

since .net 4.5 `Binding` class has [Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) property (in milliseconds):

```
Text="{Binding BalanceValue, Mode=TwoWay, Delay=333, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N2}"
```

> To avoid updating the source object with every keystroke, set the Delay property to a reasonable value to cause the binding to update only after that amount of time has elapsed since the user stopped typing.

Comment: Ow... this one is really nice. This helps a lot in some of my auto-save routines.