# WPF DataGrid can't type in comma or dots as value using PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a real problem with WPF datagrid , in fact, I have a textbox inside a datagrid column and I would like to type double value , I'm using this converter

```
 public class DoubleConverter: IValueConverter {

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
     double doubleType = (double) value;
     return doubleType.ToString();
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
     string strValue = value as string;
     double resultDouble;
     if (double.TryParse(strValue, out resultDouble)) {
       return resultDouble;
     }
     return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
   }
 }
```

This is my datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="Id_Column"  Header="{StaticResource PersonId}"   
                                          Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="11"     FontWeight="Normal"  Width="Auto" MinWidth="60" />
        <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="NameColumn" Header="{DynamicResource Name}"    Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" 
                                         FontSize="11"  FontWeight="Normal"  MinWidth="130" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  x:Name="Average"  Header="{DynamicResource Average}"  IsReadOnly="False"  Width="*" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=AvgValue,Converter={StaticResource DoubleConverter},Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="Auto"  Height="28" IsEnabled="True" >
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Unfortunately, I can't type dots in values

I saw in some posts that change `PropertyChanged` to `LostFocus` can solve the problem but I didn't want to do this because I need the `PropertyChanged` property to get the last value changed in the datagrid.

Comment: Do parse the string manually in converter, not only `TryParse` but more logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162784/wpf-updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-issue-with-double-values, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432472/textbox-updates-itself-while-typing

Answer (score 0):

For example you can bring more logic into the `ConvertBack` method. You can surely extend the posted logic to handle really wrong input.

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
{
    string strValue = value as string;
    double resultDouble;
    if(!(strValue.EndsWith(".") || strValue.EndsWith(",")) && double.TryParse(strValue, out resultDouble))
    {
        return resultDouble;
    }
    var regex = new Regex("^[0-9]+['.',',']$");
    if(regex.IsMatch(strValue))
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
            
    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```

Comment: how will it work with strings `....`, `1.2.`, etc? what if user types `..`, then moves caret and edits it into `.abcd.`?

Comment: Thank you but this solution will not works as @ASh said , the user can input two consecutive dots or maybe duplicate the dots and this not logical any more to double value.

Comment: _"You can surely extend the posted logic to handle really wrong input."_ A solution approach was posted.

Comment: @ASh How do you think it will work? ;) =>`Binding.DoNothing` and after edit to correct value, the value will be forwarded to the VM.

Comment: @abdou93 You haven't posted in your question what would you expect software should do on wrong input. Can you with posted answer input comma and dots now? Have you tried at least?

Comment: Yes I tried and the user can input more that than two dots and this is not acceptable any more

Comment: @Rekshino, so it means UI will show incorrect input as valid and won't show actual VM data. doesn't sound like a solution to me

Comment: @abdou93 I have updated an answer, I have thought logic extension you can do by yourself. Home work done now? ;)

Comment: @Rekshino I think that you didn't understand the question , the problem is that I can't input dots and the problem still using your updated answer , what do you have changed?

Comment: @abdou93 There is a link [_edited.._](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70361012/revisions) below the answer

Comment: Alright . It works but after adding some other code because the user can input for example `10.` , and this it's incorrect , So it needs an event like LostFocus to prevent getting string value instead of double