Why can't insert a decimal into a TextBox?
Here's my ViewModel:
public class ViewModelData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal? myValue;
    public decimal? MyValue
    {
        get { return myValue; }
        set
        {
            myValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyValue));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

And here's my TextBox:
<TextBox 
    Name="MyValueBox" 
    Text="{Binding MyValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="112" 
    Margin="0,96,0,0"/>

But, when I try to insert the value 1.0 for example, I can type 1, but later can't type ..
Instead, I can write text1.0, or 10 and than move cursor after 1 and type . (between 1 and 0).
Why? And how can I fix this?

Remove UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged since you cannot set a decimal? to 1..

@mm8 well, but that's why I'll miss two way binding, right?

It still binds two-way by default. If you remove UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, the source property will be set when the TextBox loses focus.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49432778/1506454, https://stackoverflow.com/q/26162784/1506454

Setting UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the binding means that your source property will be set on each key press. And you cannot set a decimal? to the value "1." in C#.
So you can either remove  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to use the default behavior of setting the source property once the focus leaves the TextBox.
Or you can try to handle the PreviewTextInput event as suggested here.

thanks man! you seems experted. what can you suggest to implement placeholders and validators on textbox in wpf? (such as "type here a decimal.." and/or check if its decimal, if its a mail, and so on). native controls seems missing.

I would encourage  to read this blog post about validation in WPF as a starting point.

I see, thanks. And for placeholder on a textbox? Can be added naivly?
