Can't enter decimal point in textbox bound to a float
I am using Dot Net 8.0 and I have created a WPF application.  On a window I wish to have a textbox control that is bound to a Float so the user can see and modify it.
I have tried many things but cannot get a version of a textbox that is bound in which I can enter a decimal point (a period).
I created a bare-bones project that has a simple window with several examples of things I have tried.  Each textbox displays a default float value correctly.  In each textbox I do the following steps consistently:

Select all the text
Backspace to clear the textbox
Attempt to type ‘-8.9’ (negative eight point nine)

Below, I recorded my steps and the results.  Following that I am including my simple example which consists of only two files.  If anyone feels energetic, you should be able to reproduce my work.
There are two approaches to this problem, one is to prevent the entry of an invalid character or a valid character in an invalid location.  The other is to allow any character but to indicate when the result is not valid with a red border.  At this point I will take either approach if it will let me enter a decimal place.
If anyone has a working example they would like to share, I will welcome it.
A.  Simple TextBox bound to a float
    a.  Cannot enter a decimal point
    b.  After backspace output says “ConvertBack cannot convert value '' (type 'String')” referring to an empty string
    c.  After entering the ‘-‘, the TextBox contains ‘-‘ and the output says “ConvertBack cannot convert value '-' (type 'String')”
    d.  After entering the ‘8’, the TextBox contains ‘-8’ and there is no output
    e.  After entering the ‘.’, the TextBox does not change and there is no output
    f.  After entering the ‘9’, the TextBox contains ‘-89’ and there is no output
B.  Simple TextBox bount to a float with a converter
    a.  Cannot enter a decimal point
    b.  After entering the backspace, the TextBox contains ‘0’ and there is no output
    c.  After entering the ‘-‘, the TextBox contains ‘-0’ and there is no output
    d.  After entering the ‘8’, the TextBox contains ‘-80’ and there is no output
    e.  After entering the ‘.’, the TextBox contains ‘-8’ and there is no output
    f.  After entering the ‘9’, the TextBox contains ‘-89’ and there is no output
C.  TextBox bount to a float with two events
    a.  Cannot enter a decimal point nor the negative sign
    b.  After entering the backspace, the TextBox is empty, and the output says “ConvertBack cannot convert value '' (type 'String')” referring to an empty string
    c.  After entering the ‘-‘, the TextBox is empty and the output says:
        i.  PreviewTextInput - TextBox Text:
        ii. PreviewTextInput - New Text: -
        iii.    PreviewTextInput - Is Valid: False
    d.  After entering the ‘8’, the TextBox contains ‘8’ and the output says:
        i.  PreviewTextInput - TextBox Text:
        ii. PreviewTextInput - New Text: 8
        iii.    PreviewTextInput - Is Valid: True
    e.  After entering the ‘.’, the TextBox still contains ‘8’ and the output says:
        i.  PreviewTextInput - TextBox Text: 8
        ii. PreviewTextInput - New Text: 8.
        iii.    PreviewTextInput - Is Valid: True
        iv. **NOTE:**  The decimal does make it into the New Text field but is not in the TextBox on the screen
    f.  After entering the ‘9’, the TextBox contains ‘89’ and the output says:
        i.  PreviewTextInput - TextBox Text: 8
        ii. PreviewTextInput - New Text: 89
        iii.    PreviewTextInput - Is Valid: True
    g.  **NOTE:** none of the debug messages in the TextInput event handler write anything.  In fact, if I put a breakpoint in the handler, it never fires.
D.  Custom TextBox bound to a float overriding OnTextInput
    a.  Cannot enter a decimal point nor the negative sign
    b.  After entering the backspace, the TextBox is clear and the output says “ConvertBack cannot convert value '' (type 'String')” referring to the empty string.
    c.  After entering the ‘8’, the TextBox contains ‘88’ and the output says:
        i.  PreviewTextInput - TextBox Text:
        ii. PreviewTextInput - New Text: 8
        iii.    PreviewTextInput - Is Valid: True
    d.  After entering the ‘.’, the TextBox still contains ‘88’ and the output says:
        i.  PreviewTextInput - TextBox Text: 88
        ii. PreviewTextInput - New Text: 88.
        iii.    PreviewTextInput - Is Valid: True
        iv. **NOTE:** the decimal point shows up in the New Text field, but not in the TextBox on the screen
    e.  After entering the ‘9’, the TextBox contains ‘8899’ and the output says:
        i.  PreviewTextInput - TextBox Text: 88
        ii. PreviewTextInput - New Text: 889
        iii.    PreviewTextInput - Is Valid: True
    f.  **NOTE:** the digits are doubled and the TextInput event handler is not fired
E.  TextBox unbound
    a.  I can enter anything I wish but the TextBox is not bound to a float
    b.  I would have to handle all the validation in the event handlers and update the backing float myself.  This would be a lot of legwork for something that should be simple.
    c.  **`NOTE:`**  This is the ONLY option where I can enter a decimal point

MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="POC_WpfFloatingPointTextBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POC_WpfFloatingPointTextBox"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:FloatToStringConverter x:Key="FloatToStringConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Label Content="Simple TextBox bound to a float"/>
            <TextBox 
                x:Name="txbA" 
                Height="20" Width="200" 
                Margin="10"
                Text="{Binding FloatA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Label Content="Simple TextBox bound to a float with a converter"/>
            <TextBox 
                x:Name="txbB" 
                Height="20" Width="200" 
                Margin="10"
                Text="{Binding FloatB, Converter={StaticResource FloatToStringConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Label Content="TextBox bound to a float with two events"/>
            <TextBox 
                x:Name="txbC" 
                Height="20" Width="200" 
                Margin="10"
                PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" 
                TextInput="TextBox_TextInput"
                Text="{Binding FloatC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Label Content="Custom TextBox bound to a float overriding OnTextInput"/>
            <local:CustomTextBox 
                x:Name="txbD" 
                Height="20" Width="200" 
                Margin="10" 
                PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" 
                TextInput="TextBox_TextInput"
                Text="{Binding FloatD, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Label Content="TextBox unbounded"/>
            <TextBox 
                x:Name="txbE" 
                Height="20" Width="200" 
                Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace POC_WpfFloatingPointTextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        #region Properties

        private float _floatA = -1.2f;
        public float FloatA
        {
            get { return _floatA; }
            set { _floatA = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FloatA)); }
        }

        private float _floatB = -2.3f;
        public float FloatB
        {
            get { return _floatB; }
            set { _floatB = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FloatB)); }
        }

        private float _floatC = -3.4f;
        public float FloatC
        {
            get { return _floatC; }
            set { _floatC = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FloatC)); }
        }

        private float _floatD = -4.5f;
        public float FloatD
        {
            get { return _floatD; }
            set { _floatD = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FloatD)); }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Private Methods

        private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            // Allow only digits, control characters, and decimal points
            TextBox? textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                string newText = textBox.Text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, e.Text);
                Debug.WriteLine($"PreviewTextInput - TextBox Text: {textBox.Text}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"PreviewTextInput - New Text: {newText}");
                bool isValid = float.TryParse(newText, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out _);
                Debug.WriteLine($"PreviewTextInput - Is Valid: {isValid}");

                e.Handled = !isValid;
            }
        }

        private void TextBox_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox? textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                string newText = textBox.Text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, e.Text);
                Debug.WriteLine($"TextInput - TextBox Text: {textBox.Text}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"TextInput - New Text: {newText}");
                bool isValid = float.TryParse(newText, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out _);
                Debug.WriteLine($"TextInput - Is Valid: {isValid}");
                if (isValid)
                {
                    textBox.Text = newText;
                    textBox.CaretIndex = newText.Length;
                }

                e.Handled = !isValid;
            }
        }

        #endregion Private Methods

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler? changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
    public class FloatToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is float f)
            {
                return f.ToString("0.##");
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (float.TryParse(value as string, out float result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            return 0f; // or other default value
        }
    }

    public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        protected override void OnTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextInput(e);

            TextBox? textBox = this;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                string newText = textBox.Text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, e.Text);
                if (float.TryParse(newText, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out _))
                {
                    textBox.Text = newText;
                    textBox.CaretIndex = newText.Length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

***** EDIT *****
Thanks to Andy's simple fix, I got the bound floating point textbox to work.  I also got an unbound textbox to work using Gerry's approach.  For completeness, I will include my two files here.
<Window x:Class="POC_WpfFloatingPointTextBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POC_WpfFloatingPointTextBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Label Content="Simple TextBox bound to a float"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--  NOTE: for this to work you must include the following in the window construtor  -->
                <!--  FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;  -->
                <TextBox 
                    x:Name="txbA" 
                    Height="20" Width="200" 
                    Margin="10" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Text="{Binding FloatA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding FloatA, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Unbound TextBox using PreviewKeyDown and PreviewTextInput"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox 
                    x:Name="txbB" 
                    Height="20" Width="200" 
                    Margin="10" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    PreviewKeyDown="TxbB_PreviewKeyDown" TextChanged="TxbB_TextChanged" Loaded="TxbB_Loaded"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding FloatB, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>



namespace POC_WpfFloatingPointTextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        #region Properties

        private float _floatA = -1.2f;
        public float FloatA
        {
            get { return _floatA; }
            set { _floatA = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FloatA)); }
        }

        private float _floatB = -3.4f;
        public float FloatB
        {
            get { return _floatB; }
            set { _floatB = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FloatB)); }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Private Methods

        private void TxbB_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox? tb = sender as TextBox;
            if (tb == null) throw new Exception("TxbB_PreviewKeyDown: tb is null");

            // Accept "one" decimal point.
            if (e.Key == Key.OemPeriod)
            {
                if (tb.Text.Contains("."))
                {
                   e.Handled = true;    // Reject.
                }

                return;   // Accept.
            }

            // Accept "one" minus sign ... "first" key only.
            if (e.Key == Key.OemMinus)
            {
                if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;    // Reject.
                }

                return;   // Accept.
            }

            // Accept digits.
            if (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9)
            {
                return;  // Accept.
            }

            if (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9)
            {
                return;  // Accept.
            }

            // Accept edit keys.
            switch (e.Key)
            {
                case Key.Back:
                case Key.Tab:

                case Key.Insert:
                case Key.Delete:

                case Key.End:
                case Key.Home:

                case Key.Left:
                case Key.Up:
                case Key.Right:
                case Key.Down:

                return;  // Accept.
            }

            // Reject key.
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        private void TxbB_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox? textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox == null) { throw new Exception("TextChanged: sender was not a TextBox");  }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text) || textBox.Text.Trim() == "-")
            {
                FloatB = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                float floatOut;
                bool isValid = float.TryParse(textBox.Text, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out floatOut);
                if (!isValid) { throw new Exception("TextChanged: TryParse failed"); }
                FloatB = floatOut;
            }
        }

        private void TxbB_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox? textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox == null) { throw new Exception("TxbI_Loaded: sender was not a TextBox"); }
            textBox.Text = FloatB.ToString();
        }

        #endregion Private Methods

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler? changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162784/wpf-updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-issue-with-double-values, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432472/textbox-updates-itself-while-typing

ASh, the solution provided by Eld Hasp works great for the decimals, but now it will not allow negative numbers.  Can it be adjusted? - Dogulas

@ASh - forgot to add the "@" before ASh.

This behaviour was introduced somewhere around net 4.5.  you can try public MainWindow()
{
FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
InitializeComponent();
}

@ASh - that works great.  If you will post that as an answer, I will accept it.


On a window I wish to have a textbox control that is bound to a Float
so the user can see and modify it. I have tried many things but cannot
get a version of a textbox that is bound in which I can enter a
decimal point (a period).

This example performs as requested; hooking PreviewKeyDown; and has a "confirm" button to show the bound float.
XAML:
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox x:Name="UxText"
             Text="{Binding Float1}"
             Width="96"
             PreviewKeyDown="UxText_PreviewKeyDown" />

    <Button x:Name="UxConfirm"
            Content="Confirm"
            Margin="8,0,0,0"
            Click="UxConfirm_Click" />
</StackPanel>

Code behind:
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

   public float Float1 { get; set; } = 1.98f;

   /// <summary>
   /// 
   /// </summary>
   public MainWindow() {

      InitializeComponent();

      this.DataContext = this;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// 
   /// </summary>
   private void UxText_PreviewKeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e ) {

      // Accept "one" decimal point.
      if ( e.Key == Key.OemPeriod ) {

         var tb = sender as TextBox;

         if ( tb.Text.Contains( "." ) ) {
            e.Handled = true;    // Reject.
         }

         return;   // Accept.
      }

      // Accept "one" minus sign ... "first" key only.
      if ( e.Key == Key.OemMinus ) {

         var tb = sender as TextBox;

         if ( tb.Text.Length > 0 ) {
            e.Handled = true;    // Reject.
         }

         return;   // Accept.
      }

      // Accept digits.
      if ( e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9 ) {
         return;  // Accept.
      }

      if ( e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9 ) {
         return;  // Accept.
      }

      // Accept edit keys.
      switch ( e.Key ) {
         case Key.Back:
         case Key.Tab:

         case Key.Insert:
         case Key.Delete:

         case Key.End:
         case Key.Home:

         case Key.Left:
         case Key.Up:
         case Key.Right:
         case Key.Down:

            return;  // Accept.
      }

      // Reject key.
      e.Handled = true;
      return;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// 
   /// </summary>
   private void UxConfirm_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
      MessageBox.Show( $"Float1: {this.Float1}" );
   }

}  // end class.


Thanks for you reply.  I really like the approach and it would work well if it weren't for the decimal point.  If the textbox is bound to a floating point number, your code would indeed allow the character, but later binding code does remove it.  This is explained here: link.   If I have to punt, I will use your solution without binding the textbox.  Thanks, Dogulas

@Dogulas A "property" can "implement" the "setter" and "getter" in any way it sees fit. I don't understand the "problem", because I never have any problems binding.

yes, you are correct.  My whole problem was that, according to Andy "This behaviour was introduced somewhere around net 4.5. ".  When I added the line in my window's constructor that he suggested, it all started working as expected.  In my example I simply bound the textbox to a float and got all the desired  behavior without needing to override PreviewKeyDown.  Your solution worked well for me as long as I added that line in the constructor.  Without that line, I would have had to user your solution without binding.
